# error handling of getopt in C

Tags: c, getopt, getopt-long

I have a question about the error handling of getopt in C:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <getopt.h>

void showFunction()
{
   printf("show function\n");
}

void printHelp()
{
   printf("print help info\n");
}

#define HELP 1
#define SHOW_OPTION 2

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{    
    const struct option long_opts[] = {{"help",      no_argument, NULL, HELP},
                                       {"show",      no_argument ,NULL, SHOW_OPTION},
                                       {NULL,   0,           NULL, 0}};
    int opt;

    while((opt = getopt_long_only(argc, argv, "", long_opts, NULL)) != -1)
    {
        switch(opt) {
            case HELP:
                printHelp();
                break;
            case SHOW_OPTION:
                showFunction();
                break;
            case '?':
                printHelp();
                break;
            default:
                printf("type base --help for details\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

this part will handle some error:

```
case '?':
                printHelp();
                break;
```

but if I type `./base --` or `./base -` or `./base sdfs` or `./base -- fsfs`, it can not handle all those invalid input, so how to handle the input above? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getopt` functions support not only options (e.g. `-h` or `--help`) but also so-called *non-option arguments*. E.g. if you write `./base --show arg1 arg2`, then `--show` is an option, but `arg1` and `arg2` are non-option arguments. Also, you can explicitly put `--` in your options to show that all argument after these dashes is a non-option argument.

In your examples, options like `-`, `sdfs`, `fsfs` are non-option arguments. `getopt_longonly` (as well as other `getopt` functions) sets the `optind` extern variable to point to the first non-option element in the `argv` array.

Let's go through your examples:

`./base --`: as `--` is the special option that shows that everything after it is not an option, this command line is perfectly valid and is equal to calling `./base` without any options.

`./base -`: the variable `optind` will have the value 1, and `argv[1]` is `"-"`. It treats single dash `-` as a non-option argument.

`./base -- fsfs`: here the `--` is ignored as it shows that after that there are only non-option arguments, and `fsfs` is the first non-option argument so `optind` will be equal to 2 and `argv[2]` is `"fsfs"`.

If you don't expect any non-option arguments, just check that the value of `optind` is equal to `argc`. If it is less then `argc` it means that you have some non-option argument:

```
if (optind < argc) {
    /* at least one non-option argument exists */
    printHelp();
}
```

Comment: yes, but some command may have non-option arguments, for example, it is valid to call the command list "base -show 1 1", but if I add this if (optind < argc) {
    /* at least one non-option argument exists */
    printHelp();
}, it will print the help info for all the vaild input

Comment: The point is that `getopt` just cannot validate non-option arguments so if it sees something that does not look like an option, e.g. `fsfs`, it skips this parameter. You should validate non-option arguments manually.

Comment: in linux, looks like the optind is not increased, if the input is base -show 1 1, the optind is 2 after the while, and base -- the optind is also 2, how to slove it

Comment: It is always equal to the position of the first non-option argument. In `-show 1 1` it points to the first 1, in `--` it points to the NULL value as there are no non-option arguments.